# Finding number of days and months in between specific date

Tags: mysql

I wanted to find number of months and days between two dates using php. How can I do that? I tried using this:

```
        $start_date = $period_start_date;
        $end_date = $period_end_date;
        write_log($start_date);
        write_log($end_date);
        $d1 = new DateTime($start_date);
        write_log($d1);
        $d2 = new DateTime($end_date);
        write_log($d2);
        $d3 = var_dump($d1 -> diff($d2) -> m);
        write_log($d3);
        $d4 = var_dump($d1 -> diff($d2) -> m + ($d1 -> diff($d2) -> y*12));
        write_log($d4);
```

In this, I wrote this write log in order to find the values of each variable. I get the values of start_date and end_date. But, others I don't get. So, what shall I do? I want to retrieve the number of months in between these days for further calculations. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the TIMESTAMPDIFF() function in MySQL.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05', '2012-06-15')
```